# Android navigation service implementation

Tags: android, android-service, android-maps-v2, android-location

I'm creating a gps/mapping app for orienteering. I'll be making use of the Google Maps Api v2 (For Android) and overlaying routes and waypoints and all of that kind of stuff. I really like how the Google 'Navigation' app that comes with the Google 'Maps' app keeps track of the navigation & gps location from what looks like a service. I.e. you can see that it still has a GPS lock and it displays waypoint information in the notification bar even when the activity is not in the foreground. Also, when you re-open the app whilst it's still in navigation mode, it opens up to and displays your position and navigation information straight away as if the app hadn't closed at all. Could anyone provide advice as to how to implement something similar or point me in the direction of open source projects that use a ‘navigation service’ type approach as outlined above.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Google Maps API for Android doesn't support the access to Routing - Information.
It is more related in the visualization of points on the map and geo - location through GPS.
So this would be the GUI - part.
When you want to have nice notifications about the current position in a route for setting up a Navig - App you would have to use the  [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/?hl=de).
You could implement your functionality within a (remote) service which is started when your app is started and keeps on running until canceled.
It's more like writing two apps, actually: One to have a nice GUI quick and one for the functionalities needed to be running in the background.
This service still could provide additional informations to your app using the AIDL / Parcelable - Objects.
All HTTP - Requests to Directions API should be running in threads, of course, to avoid io - blocking, and another separate thread handles the notifications.